# Trouble with batch requests (DELETE not working)

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We're using SAP Cloud SDK 3.32.0 and are using batch requests. Sending changes (updates of existing entities) work fine. However, DELETE of entity(set) fails. We get a message back from the SAP Gateway, saying the OData batch request is malformed. Even with a single delete in the changeset, this is the case.

After some debugging and digging (tracing on the SAP gateway), we found that the gateway apparently expects 2 empty lines after each change in a changeset (according to https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/06/batch-request-in-sap-gateway/). But when we inspect the call to the SAP Gateway, we see that there is only 1 blank line.

```
--batch_8f792254-f381-4d9f-9667-850cd1d33548
content-type: multipart/mixed;boundary=changeset_38bd1293-04f2-497e-af7e-4bacb0787023

--changeset_38bd1293-04f2-497e-af7e-4bacb0787023
content-type: application/http
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-id: 1

DELETE DienstSet(IndelingsNummer='1',RegelNummer='0000000010',Operatie='0390',OrderID='4108563') HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json

--changeset_38bd1293-04f2-497e-af7e-4bacb0787023--

--batch_8f792254-f381-4d9f-9667-850cd1d33548--
```

When we add an extra blank line in the request, just before the last `--changset...--` line and  use this in the SAP gateway client, the call gets executed OK.

So, this seems to be a bug in the SAP Cloud SDK. It somehow does not generate "batch" compliant HTTP requests.

This is a major issue for us and we need this to be fixed quite soon. Any hotfix for this?

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: This is indeed a bug in Cloud SDK side and we are working on the fix.

Comment: Any ETA on the fix?

Comment: Hi Danny, the PR for the fix is currently in review, which means we'll be able to release it soon. What's your timeframe? Is it affecting a production system?

Comment: Yes, we want to release the affected code next week.

Comment: We'll try to provide you with a Hotfix and reply here when ready.

Comment: Do you use Maven Central as repository? Or SAP Nexus?

Comment: We use maven central

Comment: It's been quiet for a few days, is there a fix yet?

Comment: Please let us know whether updating to `3.34.1` (as mentioned in the other answer) worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed in recently released SAP Cloud SDK version `3.34.1`.

Please update the dependency/ies in your project and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, it fixed our issue